# Application compiled with coarray flag (and runtime check enabled) aborting when trying to write non-contiguous array to screen

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran, fortran-coarrays

I have a fortran programme in which I have defined a 2D array. Next I wish to write all the elements of the array using a loop. For that I am using the following code:

```
program main
    use, intrinsic:: iso_fortran_env, only: output_unit, input_unit, error_unit
    implicit none

    integer :: NY = 5, NX = 4
    integer, allocatable, dimension(:, :) :: a_global
    integer, allocatable, dimension(:) :: a_temp
    integer :: i, j, me

    allocate( a_global(NY, NX), source=0 )

    do i = 1, NX
        do j = 1, NY
            a_global(j, i) = j + ( i - 1 ) * NY
        end do
    end do

    write( output_unit, * ) "a_global in image 1 (printed column-wise) = "
    do i = 1, NX
        write( output_unit, * ) a_global(:, i)
    end do
    write( output_unit, * ) ""

    write( output_unit, * ) "a_global in image 1 (printed row-wise) = "
    do i = 1, NY
        ! a_temp = a_global(i, :)
        ! write( output_unit, * ) a_temp
        write( output_unit, * ) a_global(i, :)
    end do
end program main
```

I am using intel compiler to compile the program and am using the following syntax to compile:

`ifort -check all program.f90`

When the executable is run, the first set of write commands prints the array as expected, ie, it prints all the columns of the array in a new line. But, although the second set of write commands throws the following warning before printing a row of the array in each line, it runs successfully.

```
forrtl: warning (406): fort: (1): In call to I/O Write routine, an array temporary was created for argument #1

Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
a.out              0000000000406C86  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000000403EE5  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              00000000004029DE  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc-2.17.so       00007F83EA940495  __libc_start_main     Unknown  Unknown
a.out              00000000004028E9  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

Now, I wish to code the same program in parallel and have image 1 define and write the array as above. For this I have the following modification in the code:

```
program main
    use, intrinsic:: iso_fortran_env, only: output_unit, input_unit, error_unit
    implicit none

    integer :: NY = 5, NX = 4
    integer, allocatable, dimension(:, :) :: a_global
    integer, allocatable, dimension(:) :: a_temp
    integer :: i, j, me

    sync all

    me = this_image()

    allocate( a_global(NY, NX), source=0 )

    if ( me == 1 ) then
        do i = 1, NX
            do j = 1, NY
                a_global(j, i) = j + ( i - 1 ) * NY
            end do
        end do

        write( output_unit, * ) "a_global in image 1 (printed column-wise) = "
        do i = 1, NX
            write( output_unit, * ) a_global(:, i)
        end do
        write( output_unit, * ) ""

        write( output_unit, * ) "a_global in image 1 (printed row-wise) = "
        do i = 1, NY
            ! a_temp = a_global(i, :)
            ! write( output_unit, * ) a_temp
            write( output_unit, * ) a_global(i, :)
        end do
    end if
end program main
```

This time I compile the above code using:

`ifort -coarray -check all program.f90`

Now, when I try to run the program, it throws the same warning. But this time it halts with the following additional error:

**`application called MPI_Abort(comm=0x84000004, 3) - process 0`**

I understand that the warning is shown because fortran is trying to print a set of values of the arrays which are not contiguous. But what I do not understand is why the application is aborting when I try to run it in parallel with runtime checks on. Should not it just throw the same warning and end gracefully? What am I missing here?

P.S. I am using CentOS 7 with Intel parallel studio 2017 student edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider this a bug in the Intel implementation. You should report it to Intel. I get the abort even without the warning message. The warning can be disabled by not enabling -check (specifically -check arg_temp_created)

Since you have a Student license, you'll need to do so at the Intel user forum at https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x . This sort of question is really better suited there than here.

Comment: I see. Thanks though.